# Using the command " django-admin startproject ", doesn't create anything

Tags: django

I am new to Django, command line and Stackoverflow. 
I installed python and django. 
On running the **django-admin startproject**, nothing happens.

As per some tutorials, I should get a folder made inside the Django_Practice folder. When I re-run the same command, it says, the folder already exists.

I am on Windows 10, version 1903.

```
C:\Users\Arjit Raj>python
Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 19:29:22) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> ^Z

C:\Users\Arjit Raj>python -m django --version
2.2.6

C:\Users\Arjit Raj>cd desktop

C:\Users\Arjit Raj\Desktop>cd Django_Practice

C:\Users\Arjit Raj\Desktop\Django_Practice>django-admin startproject djangotrial

C:\Users\Arjit Raj\Desktop\Django_Practice>dir
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is E21B-45DC

 Directory of C:\Users\Arjit Raj\Desktop\Django_Practice

18-Oct-19  07:06 PM    <DIR>          .
18-Oct-19  07:06 PM    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  32,418,140,160 bytes free

C:\Users\Arjit Raj\Desktop\Django_Practice>django-admin startproject djangotrial
CommandError: 'C:\Users\Arjit Raj\Desktop\Django_Practice\djangotrial' already exists

C:\Users\Arjit Raj\Desktop\Django_Practice>
```

Also, as asked in comments the result of dir /a is as mentioned below

```
C:\Users\Arjit Raj\Desktop\Django_Practice>dir /a 

Volume in drive C is Windows Volume Serial Number is E21B-45DC Directory of 

C:\Users\Arjit Raj\Desktop\Django_Practice 18-Oct-19 07:51 PM <DIR> . 
18-Oct-19 07:51 PM <DIR> .. 
0 File(s) 0 bytes 2 Dir(s) 32,417,251,328 bytes free 

C:\Users\Arjit Raj\Desktop\Django_Practice>
```

Comment: What is the output of `dir /a`?

Comment: Try with a folder which has a path not include ` ` (space). Not sure that it caused this issue in this case but mostly unpredictable issues come because that space

Comment: @krubo this is what I get. ``` C:\Users\Arjit Raj\Desktop\Django_Practice>dir /a
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is E21B-45DC

 Directory of C:\Users\Arjit Raj\Desktop\Django_Practice

18-Oct-19  07:51 PM    <DIR>          .
18-Oct-19  07:51 PM    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  32,417,251,328 bytes free

C:\Users\Arjit Raj\Desktop\Django_Practice> ```

Comment: @krubo : I am sorry, I don't know how to put all the codes in monospace form. Please guide if possible.

Comment: @RajArjit It's best to edit your question to add the additional information in the question, rather than the comments. Unfortunately, I don't know a solution to the issue.

Comment: @ToanQuocHo:  I tried with folder in the C:\Users directory. It didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the command prompt it looks like you are using Windows.
I guess, if you are having antivirus installed such as Comodo Antivirus with silent mode enabled, then it would be interfering with python scripts.

I suggest disable the Antivirus features (antivirus, firewall etc.) and then try to start a project `django-admin startproject yourprojectname`.

I faced a similar problem quite some time back, and this was one of the solutions. Hope it works for you too. 
Please do let us know the outcome, so that we can follow up. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

It has never happened to me, but it seems that it is creating the project elsewhere,  but try with this:

```sh
$_ mkdir djangotrail
$_ django-admin startproject djangotrail djangotrail
```

Comment: I tried this. It only creates the first folder which is by mkdir command. The django command doesn't do anything.

Comment: then try remove django package and reinstall

Comment: done. uninstalled both python and django. Still same issue. Is it anything to do with making a separate virtual env?